# PHP mkdir accidently creating extra directory

Tags: php, mkdir

I was working on creating a directories for new users and keep randomly naming the directory based on a random string.

The problem is when I generate a directory name and do the mkdir in php. It creates two directories instead of one. Below is the code I'm working with. How can I fix the problem so it only creates one directory instead of two?

```
$mode = '0777';  
$string = "0123456789";  
$user = '';  
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++)  
{ 
    $char = mt_rand(0, strlen($string) -1);  
    $user .= substr($string, $char, 1);  
}  
echo 'User: '.$user.' created';  
mkdir($user, $mode, false);
```

Comment: I am not seen the issue in this code, can you please check if the code (function ) executing twice.

Comment: Its only creating one, unless you call this script twice.

Comment: You need to check if the directory already exists. Use `is_dir`

Comment: You also probably mean 0777 and not '0777' for the mode

Comment: Is this from a function or class you're accidentally calling twice?

Comment: web-nomad - the is_dir function won't work because the directory is randomly generated twice so the is_dir will target the second directory not the first.

I figured out the problem. Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 doesn't respond the same way as a browser does, my bad. Clicking refresh in the Live View seems to mess up the mkdir random generator. Thanks for the help everybody, sort of. :D

Answer (score 1):

To create 10 random directory :

```
<?php
$mode = '0777';
$path = '';

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
  $dir_name = "user_".time().$i;
  mkdir($dir_name, $mode, false);
  echo 'User: '.$dir_name.' created'.'<br >';
  } 
?>
```

Comment: @VijayVerma This is the correct answer if OP wanted to create 10 random directories. But he doesn't. Did you even read the question?

Comment: @IkoTikashi tell me what you have understood plz.

Comment: OP says: "How can I fix the problem so it only creates one directory instead of two?"

Comment: In this case, it may be called the mkdir twice in his code.